# Does Skaffold has any limitations works with EKS

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

I exploring using Skaffold with our EKS cluster and I wonder if the tool is agnostic to the cloud vendor and if he can work with any k8s cluster?

Does he have any limitations regarding e.g shared volumes and other resources?

Answer (score 1):

Skaffold is a tool for deploying to any Kubernetes cluster, agnostic of cloud vendor. Skaffold can be used with any Kubernetes cluster, whether it is hosted on a cloud provider like Google's GKE, Amazon EKS, or running on-premises. Skaffold does not have any specific limitations regarding shared volumes or other resources, as it is simply a tool for deploying to a Kubernetes cluster. Any limitations you may encounter would be due to the limitations of Kubernetes itself, rather than Skaffold.

NOTE: Skaffold does poll resources it deploys for changes so API rate limits might be a possible concern but this isn't an issue for most users.

Disclaimer:  I am contributor to this project